# How to get characters to a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

I have a text file which contains the "Captured Network Packets' Headers" as hexadecimal values like this...

```
FC-C8-97-62-88-5F-74-DE-2B-C8-C7-E5-08-00-45-00-00-28-4E-C4-40-00-80-06-BD-65-C0-A8-01-03-AD-C2-7F-38-C9-96-01-BB-F8-01-7F-5F-B6-8A-15-22-50-10-40-42-72-8C-00-00.
```

I need to convert them to decimal values... I did little as here..

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("converteddata.txt");
int data = input.read();
while (data != -1) 
{
  char ch = (char) data;
  output.write(ch);
  data=input.read(); 
} 
input.close(); 
output.close();
```

Now, my problem is... how to get each hexadecimal string which would have '2' characters..? (such as "AD" or 5F etc. in order to convert them in to decimal values).

I know that C++ has a function "fgetc()" No..?  I need similar solution. Anybody can suggest a good way..? (Sorry, I'm a beginner for Java but know c++ much better)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code. Please optimize for real time uses.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("converteddata.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("data.txt")));
        String r = null;
        while((r=br.readLine())!=null) {
            String [] str = r.split("-");
            for (String string : str) {
                Long l = Long.parseLong(string.trim(), 16);
                output.write(String.valueOf(l).getBytes());
                output.write("\n".getBytes());
            }

        }
        br.close(); 
        output.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sir... But, could we keep the hyphen mark "-" without splitting it...? Because after I executed, the string became like this... 2522001519813695116222432001992298069004182199640128617511719216813

Comment: Sure..  output.write(String.valueOf(l).getBytes()); output.write("-".getBytes());

Answer (score 1):

Try `Long.parseLong("<hex string>", 16);` to convert a hexadecimal string to a `long` value.

Comment: Why not `Integer.parseInt("hexstring",16)` the given strings in this case cant be higher than 255.

Comment: @kai both would work, and in this case you're right that the strings can't be higher than 255, but for others who might be parsing larger hex strings, I felt that this would be more general purpose and usable. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Yeah Sir... It is a "Simple Solution"... Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String strHex = "FC-C8-97-62-88-5F-74-DE-2B-C8-C7-E5-08-00-45-00-00-28-4E-C4-40-00-80-06-BD-65-C0-A8-01-03-AD-C2-7F-38-C9-96-01-BB-F8-01-7F-5F-B6-8A-15-22-50-10-40-42-72-8C-00-00";

String[] hexParts = strHex.split("-");


for (String myStr : hexParts) {

  // System.out.println(toHex(myStr));
   System.out.println(toDecimal(myStr));
}


// getting For Decimal values from Hex string
public int toDecimal(String str){
    return Integer.parseInt(str.trim(), 16 );
}

// getting For Hex values
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
}
```

Comment: It also Working Sir... But I just initialized the "String strHex" as a NULL value... because that was a "PACKET-HEADER" which occurs repeatedly in that file. Thanks..!

Comment: oK Than you can updaet value of strHex at run time and use it.